# Majority Element not counting elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, element

Assume we have these 2 arrays of data

{ 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5 }

{ 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 }

After I figure out the candidate, I made a function that would then determine if that candidate is indeed the majority element in the array. For the first array example it works perfect but for the second one it does not.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
    if (arr[i] == mElement){
        count++;
    }
}

if (count> sz/2){
    majority = mElement;
    return true;
}

else{
    return false;
}
```

For the second array the majority element should obviously be 4 however my code keeps returning 5. After he count hits 10 it should switch to seeing if 4 is the majority element instead.

Can anyone please help and point me in the direction to help me solving this problem? Much appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't expect much help if you don't provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), see also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to keep track of how many times you saw each number. The best solution for this problem uses a Hashmap.

I'm not sure where you're determining the value of mElement is. How would your code know to switch to 4 as the majority element at 10. It has no way of knowing what numbers are in the rest of the array at this point in execution.

```
 int max_element( const vector<int>& arr ){

     map<int, int> total;
     for( int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
         total[arr[i]]++;
     }

     int cur_max = 0;
     int max_num = 0;
     for( auto it = total.begin(); it != total.end(); ++it){
         if ( it->second > cur_max ){
             cur_max = it->second;
             max_num = it->first;
         }
     }

     return max_num;
 }
```

This will work every time

Comment: `std::map` is not a hash map, that would be `std::unordered_map`.